# Error using json decode and curl to get or display data from facebook

Tags: php, json, facebook, curl

```
<?php

function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$status_all = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT type, app_id, comments, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())&limit=50&format=json&access_token=XXXXXX";
$status_all = json_decode(curl($status_all));

if(count($status_all)>=0){
    foreach($status_all as $status){
        echo $status->type;
    }
}

?>
```

But it returns: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file.php on line 16

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what does a `var_dump($status_all)` give you?  Also, your assignment of the URL isn't [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)'d

Comment: hmmm. weird its giving me null... Tried opening the status_all link via the browser and its giving back data. hmmm.

Comment: try to `urlencode` the `SELECT...&limit` part

Comment: This: `if(count($status_all)>=0){` is doing basically nothing - you are entering this if whether there is data to loop on or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my comments easier, answer form so it's formatted, try:

```
$q = urlencode("SELECT type, app_id, comments, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"
$status_all = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=$q&limit=50&format=json&access_token=XXXXXX";
$status_all = json_decode(curl($status_all));
```

Comment: oh great. I got it. Thanks man... Will be able to accept the answer after 2min.

Comment: No problem, was this the solution?  Or did you get it a different way?  Haha, I wasn't worried about that, was wondering if you solved it another way so you could post an answer showing how you did it ^^

Comment: I guess it was. Edited a few stuff from my code and it worked. Thanks.